# iPhone - Remove URL in current tab

Tags: ios, url

I have an iPhone running iOS 11.1.2. How do I remove the URL in my screen at the top of Safari so that I can type in a new search?

When I tap and hold, the only options I get are `copy` and `paste and go`. Formerly a small `x` appears beside the URL when I held it down and that erased the URL. That small `x` doesn't appear now.

Comment: If the whole url is selected, just over type or hit the backspace key.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to tap and hold. You can just tap the URL and you will see a 'X' icon. You can tap the X to delete the URL and enter new URL. You can also enter directly without tapping the X as the text is already selected. Typing over will delete the existing text.

[image]